# Spring Security 3.0 Redirect to page that timed out

Tags: java, spring, security, redirect

I am using Spring Security 3.0.6 and I would like to be able to do the following:

If the user is a on a page and a session timeout occurs, the user will be taken to the log in page and on valid log in redirected back to the page the timeout occurred on.

I currently have the following in my security.xml file.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/main" 
        always-use-default-target="false"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <remember-me/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login" />
</http>
```

This is my authentication class:

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {

    String url = "";

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest) session.getAttribute(WebAttributes.SAVED_REQUEST);
        if (savedRequest != null) {
            url = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("url: "+ url);

    if (url == "") {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/main");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(url);
    }
}
```

}

I send the user back to the log in page via javascript like:

```
window.location.href="/login";
```

The url is always null in my authentication class.  How can I make this work so Spring will redirect to the correct page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to write any custom code since Spring Security can do that by default. Take a look to the documentation regarding `authentication-success-handler-ref` [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-openid-login).

> **authentication-success-handler-ref**
>
> This can be used as an alternative to default-target-url and always-use-default-target, giving you full control over the navigation flow after a successful authentication. The value should be the name of an AuthenticationSuccessHandler bean in the application context. **By default, an implementation of [SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) is used** and injected with the default-target-url.
>
> Reference to an AuthenticationSuccessHandler bean which should be used to handle a successful authentication request. **Should not be used in combination with default-target-url (or always-use-default-target)** as the implementation should always deal with navigation to the subsequent destination.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  How does spring handle that by default?  If the user comes to the log in page for the first time I need to direct them to /main.  If they timed out from another page I need them to go to /anotherpage.  How can i make this happen with SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler?  A code example would be helpful.  Thanks

Comment: It is the usual behaviour of Spring if you don't define `authentication-success-handler-ref`. Just remove it from your configuration.

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding something.  I removed authentication-success-handler-ref.  How does spring know which page cause the timeout?  I want to be redirected back to that page after the login screen.  I tried this out and it keeps taking me to the normal default screen after login.

Comment: Timeout is not caused by a page but by user inactivity. If the session has expired and the user requests any page that requires authentication, login form will be displayed. After login, user will be taken to the page that he requested after session expiration, not to the page where he was when timeout happends.

Comment: Ok I understand now.  Thank you for the explaining.  I think my problem is that I am not requesting another page.  I doing an ajax call to update content on the same page.  Is there something I can add in my controller?

Comment: I see. You need custom code, it's clear. It is complex, because the user requests an url (ajax call), but you want to display another (the one (from where call is done). I don't know how to do it, but a let you an idea. First, take a look to http://goo.gl/fNi56 (see how to get SavedRequest because maybe you are doing something wrong). Then, once you have the last url the use requested, maybe you can make a map between that URL and the one you want to display and take the user to that one.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments on the previous answer, I see 2 options.

1. Create a customized RequestCache, for example by extending HttpSessionRequestCache and avoiding to put ajax requests on that cache, you on login you should be redirected to you last none Ajax request
2. Implement your own RedirectStrategy to send a custom ajax response that will be interpreted by you client side code. In some cases setting the custom RedirectStrategy is not easy because there are no configuration attributes for the different element, for example, in the case of the SessionManagementFilter you will need to create you own instance and set the custom redirect strategy

I hope it helps